# Como verificar qual o arquivo mais recente em uma pasta com Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo

Supondo que tenha uma pasta com diversos arquivos `.txt`, com diferentes nomes, preciso saber qual o arquivo mais recente.

Como faço isso utilizando Python?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o módulo [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

```
from pathlib import Path

data_criacao = lambda f: f.stat().st_ctime
data_modificacao = lambda f: f.stat().st_mtime

directory = Path('/seu/diretorio')
files = directory.glob('*.txt')
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=data_modificacao, reverse=True)

for f in sorted_files:
    print(f)
```

Assim, será apresentado na tela o nome dos arquivos por ordem de modificação, do último modificado ao primeiro. Caso queira utilizar a data de criação, mude para `st_ctime`, utilizando `data_criacao` em `key`.

Answer (score 5):

Tendo em vista a boa resposta do colega Woss, sugiro algumas modificações:

Ao invés de criar uma função (lambda) para o tempo (criação ou modificação):

```
data_criacao = lambda f: f.stat().st_ctime
data_modificacao = lambda f: f.stat().st_mtime
```

Faça o uso dos métodos nativos de `os.path`:

- [`os.path.getctime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime): usado para obter o tempo de criação do arquivo
- [`os.path.getmtime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime): usado para obter o tempo da ultima modificação do arquivo

Exemplo:

```
from pathlib import Path
from os.path import getmtime

directory = Path('/pasta/aonde/ficam/os/arquivos')
files = directory.glob('*.txt')
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=getmtime, reverse=True)

for f in sorted_files:
    print(f)
```

Algo muito importante é que para o caso da data de criação do arquivo, tanto o `f.stat().st_ctime` quanto a checagem via `os.path.getctime` em alguns sistemas (como Unix) ele usará os metadados da hora da **última modificação do arquivo**.

É importante dizer que o uso `Path()` apesar de facilitar entre situações do `WindowsPath` e `PosixPath`, ou até mesmo para "reaproveitar", mas não parece ser o caso (necessidade), se for tudo bem, mas caso não o uso de `glob.iglob(pathname, *, recursive=False)` deve ser mais que suficiente:

> Citei o `iglob()` ao invés de `glob.glob()`, pois ele, assim como o `Path().glob()`, retornam um [**iterador**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), o que irá consumir menos memória que o `glob.glob()` (que retorna um `list()`).

Se for algo simples mesmo poderia ficar apenas:

```
from glob import iglob
from os.path import getmtime


files = iglob('/pasta/aonde/ficam/os/arquivos/*.txt')
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=getmtime, reverse=True)

for f in sorted_files:
    print(f)
```

Se o objetivo é obter apenas o arquivo especifico e não listar a pasta, você pode usar o método `max()`, ao invés do `sorted`:

```
from pathlib import Path
from os.path import getmtime

directory = Path('/pasta/aonde/ficam/os/arquivos')
files = directory.glob('*.txt')

arquivo_mais_recente = max(files, key=getmtime)

print(arquivo_mais_recente)
```

ou com `iglob`:

```
from glob import iglob
from os.path import getmtime


files = iglob('/pasta/aonde/ficam/os/arquivos/*.txt')

arquivo_mais_recente = max(files, key=getmtime)

print(arquivo_mais_recente)
```

Daria para usar `scandir()` e com um `for:` mais uma variável ir checando o valor anterior para ver se é menor, através do `os.path.getmtime` com uma simples `if:`

```
from os import scandir
from os.path import getmtime


files = scandir('/pasta/aonde/ficam/os/arquivos/')
mais_antigo = 0
arquivo_mais_recente = None

for entry in files:
    if entry.is_file() and entry.name.lower().endswith('.txt'):
        modificado_em = getmtime(entry.path)

        if mais_antigo < modificado_em:
            mais_antigo = modificado_em
            arquivo_mais_recente = entry.path

print(arquivo_mais_recente)
```

O que não é necessariamente vantajoso se comparado ao `Path().glob()` ou `glob.iglob()`, mas ajuda a entender a lógica (o que pode aproveitar se for portar algo semelhante para uma linguagem que não tenha algo equivalente ao `iglob`).

---

Outro detalhe, sendo esse apenas **um adicional**, com `Path().glob()` para fazer o processo de maneira recursiva você pode usar `**`, exemplo:

```
from pathlib import Path

directory = Path('/pasta/aonde/ficam/os/arquivos')
files = directory.glob('**/*.txt')
```

Dessa maneira irá buscar tanto na pasta desejada quanto em suas subpastas. Já o equivalente em `iglob` seria definir o parâmetro `recursive=` como `True`:

```
from glob import iglob

iglob('/pasta/aonde/ficam/os/arquivos/*.txt', recursive=True)
```