# Galeria de fotos ordenada em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, galeria, classificação

Estou desenvolvendo uma galeria de imagens listando elas de um diretório.
O que falta eu fazer é separar estas imagens ou ordenar por ordem de criação,
tenho um script que gera as imagens da seguinte forma.

```
pessoa_ID_N.jpg
```

onde ID é o número do id da pessoa e N é o número da foto desta pessoa que pode variar de 0 a 9.

meu script lista todas as fotos da pasta. O que eu preciso fazer é, listar pela ordem de criação ou separar com um `<hr>` cada grupo de ID`s criados.

Meu código:

```
#!/bin/python

import os
from flask import Flask, Response, request, abort, render_template_string, send_from_directory
from PIL import Image
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO


app = Flask(__name__)

WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 800

TEMPLATE = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.img-responsive{
        max-width:100%;
}
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K$
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.10.0/css/lightbox.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.10.0/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    {% for image in images %}
    <div class='col-md-2' style="min-height:300px">
        <a class="image" href="{{ image.src }}" style="width: {{ image.width }}px; height: {{ image.height }}px" data-lightbox="faces">
            <img src="{{ image.src }}" data-src="{{ image.src }}?w={{ image.width }}&amp;h={{ image.height }}" class="img-responsive" />
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
</div>
</body>
'''

@app.route('/<path:filename>')
def image(filename):
    try:
        w = int(request.args['w'])
        h = int(request.args['h'])
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        return send_from_directory('.', filename)

    try:
        im = Image.open(filename)
        im.thumbnail((w, h), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        io = StringIO.StringIO()
        im.save(io, format='JPEG')
        return Response(io.getvalue(), mimetype='image/jpeg')

    except IOError:
        abort(404)

    return send_from_directory('.', filename)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    images = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        for filename in [os.path.join(root, name) for name in files]:
            if not filename.endswith('.jpg'):
                continue
            im = Image.open(filename)
            w, h = im.size
            aspect = 1.0*w/h
            if aspect > 1.0*WIDTH/HEIGHT:
                width = min(w, WIDTH)
                height = width/aspect
            else:
                height = min(h, HEIGHT)
                width = height*aspect
            images.append({
                'width': int(width),
                'height': int(height),
                'src': filename
            })

    return render_template_string(TEMPLATE, **{
        'images': images
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='::')
```

já procurei nos manuais de Python e outras funções mas ao tentar implementar o script para de funcionar. Alguém poderia me orientar em como fazer ou dar um help com isto ?

---

Problema resolvido.

segue como ficou o cod:

```
def index():
    images = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
        for filename in [os.path.join(root, name) for name in files]:
            if not filename.endswith('.jpg'):
                continue
            im = Image.open(filename)
            w, h = im.size
            aspect = 1.0*w/h
            if aspect > 1.0*WIDTH/HEIGHT:
                width = min(w, WIDTH)
                height = width/aspect
            else:
                height = min(h, HEIGHT)
                width = height*aspect
            images.append({
                'width': int(width),
                'height': int(height),
                'src': filename
            })

    return render_template_string(TEMPLATE, **{
        'images': images
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='::')
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como verificar qual o arquivo mais recente em um pasta com Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292823/como-verificar-qual-o-arquivo-mais-recente-em-um-pasta-com-python)

Comment: Com o que respondi nesta outra pergunta, basta você fazer `sorted(files, key=data_criacao)`

Comment: Então Anderson eu vo seu post e ate consegui rodar ele mas não consigo adaptar o sorted no meu script. Pode me dizer onde ele entraria por favor?

Comment: No seu `for`, que itera sobre os arquivos.

Comment: Obrigado vou tentar e ja respondo.

Comment: consegui, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Graças a ajuda do Anderson o cod funcionando ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
def index():
    images = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
        for filename in [os.path.join(root, name) for name in files]:
            if not filename.endswith('.jpg'):
                continue
            im = Image.open(filename)
            w, h = im.size
            aspect = 1.0*w/h
            if aspect > 1.0*WIDTH/HEIGHT:
                width = min(w, WIDTH)
                height = width/aspect
            else:
                height = min(h, HEIGHT)
                width = height*aspect
            images.append({
                'width': int(width),
                'height': int(height),
                'src': filename
            })

    return render_template_string(TEMPLATE, **{
        'images': images
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='::')
```