# Comparar datas em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, if

Boa tarde !
    Preciso resolver o seguinte cenário em python: possuo um ou mais arquivos .txt em uma pasta, mas quero retornar apenas os arquivos que tiverem a data de modificação de acordo com a data que eu quiser (inicial e final), porém não estou conseguindo fazer essa comparação como data com a entrada do usuário:

```
import re
import os
from datetime import datetime as dt


#definindo datas
dtEntradaInicial = input('Data inicial: ')
dtEntradaFinal = input('Data final: ')

print(datetime.strptime(dtEntradaInicial, "%d/%m/%y").date())
print(datetime.strptime(dtEntradaFinal, "%d/%m/%y").date())

#testando retorno de data de modificação do arquivo
modificacao = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime('/c:/arquivoteste.txt'))
print('A data de modificação do arquivo é: ', modificacao)

if modificacao >= dtEntradaInicial and modificacao <= dtEntradaFinal:
   print('Consegui comparar datas com sucesso!')
```

Comment: `dtEntradaInicial` e `dtEntradaFinal` são strings. Tu está convertendo as strings para date, mas não está salvando em lugar algum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você está convertendo o input do usuário para `date` mas não está guardando o resultado.

Você rpecisa salvar o input convertido numa variável. Ex.:

```py
from datetime import datetime

# Recebendo input do usuário (como string)
input_data_inicial = input('Data inicial:')
input_data_final = input('Data final:')

# Convertendo input para datetime.datetime
data_inicial = datetime.strptime(input_data_inicial, "%d/%m/%y")
data_final = datetime.strptime(input_data_final, "%d/%m/%y")

# apenas para demonstração atribui um valor 'hard-coded' para data_modificao
data_modificacao = datetime.now()

if data_inicial <= data_modificacao <= data_final:
    print('data_modificacao está entre o período selecionado')
else:
    print('data_modificacao está fora do período selecionado')
```

Veja o código em ação no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/verificando-se-data-esta-em-determinado-periodo)

Comment: Não é comum em Python prefixar o tipo de uma variável com um mnemonico do seu tipo - o "dt" no caso de variáveis como "dtEntradaInicial" . Não é proibido, e há ocasiões em que pode ajudar, é certo. Uma vez que por coincidência o AP usa esses prefixos, _e_ o problema em questão tem justamente a ver com isso, achei que seria legal refletir isso na resposta. Então editei-a para refletir melhor os tipos em cada momento. (variável é entrada como `strEntradaInicial`, e depois é convertida pra outro tipo).

Comment: @jsbueno Eu só tinha modificado o código dele. Porém a edição é muito bem vinda. Faz todo o sentido e melhora bastante a resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: @fernandosavio Vale lembrar também que você pode fazer `a < x < b` em Python para verificar se `x` está entre `a` e `b`.

Comment: Visto que a resposta pode melhorar, vou editar a questão para que não apenas reflita o exemplo citado pelo OP mas se torne mais útil. Obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 4):

Aproveitando a lógica demonstrada na [resposta do fernandosavio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327551/5878) e integrando com a [minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/292828/5878) sobre como listar arquivos recentes de um diretório, você pode fazer algo como:

```
import time

from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

def filtro_data_modificacao(inicial, final, *, formato='%d/%m/%y'):

    # Gera o timestamp a partir das datas de entrada:
    inicial = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(inicial, formato).timetuple())
    final = time.mktime(datetime.strptime(final, formato).timetuple())

    def filtro(arquivo):
        return inicial <= arquivo.stat().st_mtime <= final

    return filtro

diretorio = Path('/seu/diretorio')
arquivos = directory.glob('*.txt')
arquivos_modificados = filter(filtro_data_modificacao('01/09/18', '05/09/18'), arquivos)

for arquivo in arquivos_modificados:
    print(arquivo)
```

Assim, ao fazer `filtro_data_modificacao('01/09/18', '05/09/18')` você gera um filtro que retornará `true` se um determinado arquivo foi modificado neste intervalo. Você ainda pode, se necessário, definir o formato da entrada caso, por exemplo, precise informar o ano com quatro dígitos:

```
filter(filtro_data_modificacao('01/09/2018', '05/09/2018', formato='%d/%m/%Y'), arquivos)
```