# Como verificar se a data de hoje corresponde a uma data criada em uma aplicação Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, cron

Eu tenho uma aplicação que recebe o dia da semana e a hora em que um evento deve ocorrer.
Além disso, recebe também o período de tempo que as pessoas devem confirmar presença.
Meu modelo segue abaixo:

```py
def validar_apenas_um(obj):
    model = obj.__class__
    if model.objects.count() > 0 and obj.id != model.objects.get().id:
        raise ValidationError("Você só pode adicionar um horário")

class ModelPresenca(models.Model):
    DIAS = (
        ('Domingo', 'Domingo'),
        ('Segunda', 'Segunda'),
        ('Terça', 'Terça'),
        ('Quarta', 'Quarta'),
        ('Quinta', 'Quinta'),
        ('Sexta', 'Sexta'),
        ('Sábado', 'Sábado'),
    )
    dia = models.CharField('Dia da Pelada', max_length=10, help_text='Escolha o dia da pelada', choices=DIAS)
    hora_pelada = models.TimeField('Horário da pelada (ex: 19:30)', help_text='Hora em que sua pelada é realizada')
    dias_antecedencia = models.PositiveIntegerField('Dias antecedência',
                                                    default=1,
                                                    validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(6)],
                                                    help_text='Em quantos dias de antecência os peladeiros devem '
                                                              'marcar presença')
```

Eu tenho feito algumas coisas à parte os quais ainda não juntei na minha aplicação Django, pois não sei se é o melhor caminho.
Por exemplo, penso em pegar o dia da semana escolhido pelo usuário e converter para inteiro (0 a 6) através da função "dia_semana", para que com isso a função dia_da_pelada receba esse número, bem como a hora escolhida (TimeField) pelo usuário, retornando, assim, a data no formato %Y:%M:%D %H:%M.
Por sua vez, a função "data_inicio_confirmar" receberá o número de dias e a data do evento para poder retornar a abertura para a confirmação com antecedência:

```py
"""
    Converting the day of the week (string) to an integer because the date object receives numbers for year, month, and day.  
"""
def dia_semana(dia):
    switcher = {
        'Segunda': 0,
        'Terça':   1,
        'Quarta':  2,
        'Quinta':  3,
        'Sexta':   4,
        'Sábado':  5,
        'Domingo': 6,
    }

    return switcher.get(dia)

"""
    Day of the event.  
"""
def dia_pelada(dia, hora=' 19:30'):

    data_atual = datetime.today()
    dia_datetime = date(data_atual.year, data_atual.month, data_atual.day)

    if data_atual.weekday() > dia:
        delta_dia = abs(dia - data_atual.weekday()) + 1
    else:
        delta_dia = abs(dia - data_atual.weekday())
    print(delta_dia)
    dia_datetime += timedelta(days=delta_dia)
    dia_string = '{}-{}-{}'.format(dia_datetime.year, dia_datetime.month, dia_datetime.day)
    # to see how to convert TimeField to String
    dia_string = dia_string + hora
    return datetime.strptime(dia_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

def data_inicio_confirmar(num, data_pelada):
    hora_inicio = ' 00:00:01'
    data_inicio = '{}-{}-{}'.format(data_pelada.year, data_pelada.month, data_pelada.day-num)
    data_inicio = data_inicio + hora_inicio
    return data_inicio
```

Eu estou pensando no seguinte algoritmo para finalizar essa parte, mas eu não sei como fazer com que isto se repita toda semana sem precisar que o usuário fique sempre adicionando as mesmas informações.
Se alguém puder meu ajudar ou indicar um caminho, eu agradeço.

```py
week_d = dia_semana('Sexta') 
event_d = dia_pelada(week_d)
conf_d = data_inicio_confirmar(1, event_d) 


n = datetime.now()
t_str = '{}-{}-{}'.format(n.year, n.month, n.day)
t_hour = ' {}:{}'.format(n.hour, n.minute)
today = t_str + t_hour
datetime.strptime(today, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
if (conf_d == today) and (today < event_d):
    # call my formulary to confirm presence
else:
    # another thing
```

Comment: dê uma olhada nesse link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327545/comparar-datas-em-python, é isso que você procura?

Comment: Olá @Renan, muito obrigado pelo feedback! Mas não é isso não. Seria algo parecido com o crontab do linux, onde eu pudesse agendar eventos nos horários citados acima. Seria deixar aberto um formulário no horário estabelecido até o dia e a hora em que o evento vai se realizar, como uma lista de presença. Eu tava vendo que isso pode ser feito com Celery. Quer dizer, eu postei minha dúvida no Stackoverflow em inglês e me responderam assim. De qualquer forma, eu agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: @Thales, Não me vem em mente nada que possa te ajudar diretamente no momento, mas tenho uma ideia do que pode te servir, e é bem simples, você citou o crontab e acho que você poderia usar justamente ele para isso, como? você pode agendar a maguina para enviar uma solicitação via url ao django, onde você configuraria para que ele reagisse de determinado jeito quando recebesse esse digamos "aviso", é só uma sugestão, mas caso me venha alguma luz do que possa te ajudar ou precisa que eu explique a minha ideia acima eu volto. Imagino que o Thread do Python pode também ajudar

Comment: @GuilhermeFrançadeOliveira, obrigado pela atenção dispensada! É, eu já pensei em fazer pelo Crontab. Talvez eu tente algo desse jeito. Agradeço se puder me dar mais alguma ideia. Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: Minha resposta está detalhada no stackoverflow em inglês: [link para questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647016/how-to-return-a-django-view-from-within-a-celery-task)

Comment: Minha resposta está detalhada no _Stackoverflow_ em inglês: [link para a solução que encontrei pra mim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647016/how-to-return-a-django-view-from-within-a-celery-task)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução e até já mencionaste, é utilizar **Celery & RabbitMQ**. Desenvolvi recentemente uma solução de streaming que implica efetuar cálculos de custo de processamento um pouco elevados. A minha escolha recaiu em criar tasks com Celery e RabbitMQ, tens [aqui](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html) um exemplo. Adicionalmente e já incluido neste, **permite também criar tarefas periódicas, 10 em 10 min. todos os dias, semanas** etc. partilho exemplo e prints de configuração no admin do Django, penso que é isto que precisas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma parte do meu exemplo:

Como é criada uma nova task via outra função....com **.delay()**

```
 validate_errors.delay()
```

E essa chamada da função com o .delay, irá enviar uma mensagem para o broker, o RabbitMQ, com o que é para processar, o nome do ficheiro por exemplo e o id da task, os workers disponíveis irão processar o upload logo que possível....este é um resumo do fluxo...qualquer questão adicional dispõe.

```
@task
def validate_errors():
    cpu = psutil.cpu_percent()
    if cpu < 60:
        return 'Done ERRORS validation validate_errors()'
    return 'CPU Busy validate_errors()'
```

NOTA: Podes utilizar outro broker, Redis por exemplo.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta e atenção dispensada! Desculpe-me também pela demora em responder! Estou de viagem esses dias, mas, logo mais, retornarei. Como esse deve ser mesmo o caminho, marcarei sua resposta como a correta, assim que conseguir. E obrigado por se dispor em ajudar. Perguntarei, se precisar!