# Como pegar a ultima data de atualização de um arquivo em python

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber como posso pegar a data completa(dia/mes/ano e hora/minuto/segundo)  da ultima atualização de um arquivo em excel?

Answer (score 1):

Como discutido em [Como verificar qual o arquivo mais recente em um pasta com Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/292823/5878) você pode usar a propriedade `st_mtime` do arquivo:

```
from pathlib import Path

diretorio = Path('.')
arquivo = diretorio/'data.txt'

print(arquivo.stat().st_mtime)
```

Isso te dará o *timestamp* da última modificação, então basta convertê-lo para data com o módulo [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)