# Ordenação de nome do arquivo php

Tags: php, classificação

Tenho um código php, que uso para disponibilizar arquivos aos clientes, porém preciso que ele ordene o nome do arquivo do maior para o menor, por exemplo, tenho os arquivos:

```
2019 Arquivo 1

2018 Arquivo 2

2017 Arquivo 3
```

Preciso que eles fiquem com essa ordenação.

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.pdf") as $arquivo) {
    echo "<a href='$arquivo'>$arquivo</a><br>" ;

}
?>
```

Comment: Como tentou ordenar? Qual foi o resultado obtido?

Comment: Estava tentando utilizar o (comando filemtime()), mais não consegui obter nenhum resultado.

Comment: Victor, então essa solução é útil? [Como verificar qual o arquivo mais recente em um pasta com Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/292823/5878)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o "rsort" para ordenar de maneira decrescente a lista de arquivos devolvida pelo "glob". Por exemplo:

```
$lista = glob("*.pdf");
rsort($lista);
foreach ($lista as $arquivo) {
    echo "<a href='$arquivo'>$arquivo</a><br>" ;
}
```

O resultado será:

```
2019 Arquivo 1.pdf
2018 Arquivo 2.pdf
2017 Arquivo 3.pdf
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho, muito obrigado mesmo, grande abraço!