# Pegar último arquivo que entrou na pasta "Downloads"

Tags: python, arquivo, path

Como posso abrir o último arquivo que foi baixado na pasta *"Downloads"* com Python?

Vi várias opções com as *libs* `os.path` e `os.walk` mas nenhuma delas possibilita pegar o último arquivo que entrou no diretório.

Na plataforma Colab (da Google) e utilizando Linux, vi uma pessoa fazendo:

```
!ls -1t *.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

você pode utilizar a função `glob` do python desta forma:

```
import glob
import os.path

folder_path = r'C:\Users\MasterRoot\Desktop\Test'
file_type = '\*csv' # se nao quiser filtrar por extenção deixe apenas *
files = glob.glob(folder_path + file_type)
max_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)

print (max_file)
```

ele vai te retornar o ultimo arquivo adicionado a este diretorio.

Comment: O mesmo pode ser usado com a biblioteca `os`. `files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, f))]`. Embora o comando seja mais comprido, não há necessidade de carregar outra biblioteca.

Comment: vdd neste ponto vc tem razao

Comment: glob.glob pode consumir muita memória, o melhor é usar glob.iglob, esse que usa um [iterador](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator). Uma resposta que formulei dedicada a isso: [Como verificar qual o arquivo mais recente em um pasta com Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/522882/3635)

Answer (score 0):

Para obter o último arquivo de uma pasta você pode usar o metadado `data de modificação`, o último arquivo baixado é o que tem a **data de modificação mais recente**

[image: O último arquivo tem a data de modificação mais recente]

## obter o `path` da pasta downloads

você pode obter o path de pasta downloads tanto no linux quanto no windows usando o código abaixo:

```py
def get_download_path():
    """Returns the default downloads path for linux or windows"""
    if os.name == 'nt':
        import winreg
        sub_key = r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders'
        downloads_guid = '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'
        with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sub_key) as key:
            location = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, downloads_guid)[0]
        return location
    return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'downloads')
```

## Obter o último arquivo

Agora que temos o path da pasta downloads, temos que obter o path de cada arquivos dentro dela usando a lib `glob`, ler a data de modificação de cada arquivo usando o `os.path.getmtime()` e pegamos o arquivo que tiver o maior.

```py
def get_latest_file_path(path):
    """return the more recent file in a path"""

    file_paths = glob.glob(f'{path}/*') # obtem o path de cada arquivo na pasta
    all_files_modification_time = [ os.path.getmtime(path) for path in file_paths ] # Obtem o modification time de cada arquivo
    latest_file_index = all_files_modification_time.index(max(all_files_modification_time)) # obtem o index do maior deles, o arquivo mais recente
    return file_paths[latest_file_index]
```

após isso basta abrir o arquivo usando o path retornado

código completo abaixo:

```py
import os, glob

def get_download_path():
    """Returns the default downloads path for linux or windows"""

    if os.name == 'nt':
        import winreg
        sub_key = r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders'
        downloads_guid = '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'
        with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sub_key) as key:
            location = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, downloads_guid)[0]
        return location
    return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'downloads')


def get_latest_file_path(path):
    """return the latest file in a path"""

    file_paths = glob.glob(f'{path}/*')
    all_files_modification_time = [ os.path.getmtime(path) for path in file_paths ]
    latest_file_index = all_files_modification_time.index(max(all_files_modification_time))
    return file_paths[latest_file_index]


downloads_path = get_download_path()
latest_file_path = get_latest_file_path(downloads_path)

with open(latest_file_path, 'r') as file:
    pass
    # seu código ...
```